# Visual Studio Config File Editor - Not Formatting

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide, configuration-files

My VS 2008 seems to be acting a bit weird and the solution is eluding me.

The problem is that if I open a config file; app.config or web.config, this looks and behaves as a plain text document.

I have no formatting, no coloring, no intellisense and no collapsible or expandable regions.

I have reset all setting and restored default file associations.

If I go into the setting menu, Text Editor, XML, formatting I see an error "An error occurred loading this property page"

Has any one seen this before and have you go a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Choose Toolbox Items: An error occurred loading this property page.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1126081.aspx)

Try running

> devenv /setup

[/Setup (devenv.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex6a2fad(VS.80).aspx)